# How to make the dropdown options the same style as the select element?

Tags: css, bulma

I'm using Bulma to style my page. For some reason, the options in the dropdown list dont match the style of the select element itself, see this screenshot:

[image]

Im running the site on a localhost with ubuntu 18.04, using firefox. The site uses angular, here is the code for the select menu.

```
    <div class="select is-success is-fullwidth selectOverflowStopped">
      <select [(ngModel)] = "leasing" (change)="setLeasingPrice()">
        <option [ngValue]="0.0014" >12 Monate ( 0.14%) </option>
        <option [ngValue]="0.0011">24 Monate ( 0.11%) </option>
        <option [ngValue]="0.001">48 Monate ( 0.1%) </option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

I already read a few other posts on SO on this topic, but none of them had to deal with the issue that the option elements BY DEFAULT render differently than the select element.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting `<option>` with devtool ? Does Bulma or Angular applies a style to them by default ? Is there anything overiding their style in your CSS ?

Comment: So far I can't find anything, neither on the select element, nor on the option elements :( That's why I'm coming here ^^

Comment: Have you tried using `-moz-appearance:none;` on your select / options and see if it changes ?

Comment: @Jake Not yet, but now I tried. unfortunately, it didn't change anything. I made a test class, filled it with "-moz-appearance:none !important;"  to make sure the rule is enforced (for testing purposes). Nothing happened, I tried it on the option elements directly, then the above select element and then the div wrapper. Always the same behavior, nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

[I have overriden](https://github.com/FOE-Tools/FOE-Tools.github.io/blob/develop/layouts/_default/style/theme/dark/_overrides.scss#L106-L116) the default behavior in my case, because on Firefox (on Linux anyway, for other OS I don't know) it takes the style from Gtk theme.

So add something like that in your style should solve the problem:

```css
select option {
  color: white !important;
}

select option, select optgroup {
  background-color: #363636 !important;
}

::placeholder {
  color: #aaa !important;
}
```

Comment: Have you add this style [**after** the call to the buefy style](https://github.com/FOE-Tools/FOE-Tools.github.io/blob/develop/layouts/_default/style.scss#L52-L53) ?